# Fold second-level links recursively in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Using Scrapy, I am trying to scrape a link network from Wikipedia across all languages. Each Wikipedia page should contain a link to a Wikidata item that uniquely identifies the topic of the page across all languages. The process I am trying to implement looks like this:

1. First, extract the Wikidata link from each page (the "source" link).
2. Iterate through the remaining links on the page.
3. For each link, send a request to the corresponding page (the "target" link), with a new callback function.
4. Extract the Wikidata link from the corresponding target page.
5. Iterate through all the links on the target page and call back to the original `parse` function.

Basically, I want to skip over the intermediate link on a given source page and instead grab its corresponding Wikidata link.

Here is the (semi-working) code that I have so far:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse
from scrapy import Spider    
from wiki_network.items import WikiNetworkItem

WD = \
    "//a/@href[contains(., 'wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityPage') \
    and not(contains(., '#'))][1]"

TARGETS = \
    "//a/@href[contains(., '/wiki/') \
    and not(contains(., 'wikidata')) \
    and not(contains(., 'wikimedia'))]"

class WikiNetworkSpider(Spider):
    name = "wiki_network"
    allowed_domains = ["wikipedia.org"]    
    start_urls = ["https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Derrida"]
    filter = re.compile(r"^.*(?!.*:[^_]).*wiki.*")               

    def parse(self, response):        

        # Extract the Wikidata link from the "source" page
        source = response.xpath(WD).extract_first()       

        # Extract the set of links from the "source" page                         
        targets = response.xpath(TARGETS).extract()                
        if source:                
            source_title = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract_first()                                      
            for target in targets:   
                if self.filter.match(str(target)) is not None:
                    item = WikiNetworkItem()        
                    item["source"] = source
                    item["source_domain"] = urlparse(response.url).netloc
                    item["refer"] = response.url
                    item["source_title"] = source_title  

                    # Yield a request to the target page
                    yield Request(url=urljoin(response.url, str(target)), \
                                  callback=self.parse_wikidata, \
                                  meta={"item": item})

    def parse_wikidata(self, response):
        item = WikiNetworkItem(response.meta["item"])
        wikidata_target = response.xpath(WD).extract_first()
        if wikidata_target:      

            # Return current item
            yield self.item_helper(item, wikidata_target, response)

            # Harvest next set of links            
            for s in response.xpath(TARGETS).extract():
                if self.filter.match(str(s)) is not None:
                    yield Request(url=urljoin(response.url, str(s)), \
                                  callback=self.parse, meta={"item": item})

    def item_helper(self, item, wikidata, response):
        print()
        print("Target: ", wikidata)        
        print()
        if item["source"] != wikidata:                
            target_title = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract_first()                            
            item["target"] = wikidata
            item["target_title"] = target_title
            item["target_domain"] = urlparse(response.url).netloc
            item["target_wiki"] = response.url                                    
            print()
            print("Target: ", target_title)            
            print()
            return item
```

The spider runs and scrapes links for a while (the scraped item count typically reaches 620 or so), but eventually it builds up a massive queue, stops scraping altogether, and just continues to crawl. Should I expect it to begin scraping again at some point?

It seems as though there should be an easy way to do this kind of second-level scraping in Scrapy, but the other questions I've read so far seem to be mostly about how to handle paging in Scrapy, but not how to "fold" a link in this way.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You want to magically extract data from a page which doesn't contain it? Also, I can't reproduce yyour problem with not scraping items, I stopped the crawl after a while and got `wc -l stuffs.jl` -> `1967 stuffs.jl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long you spider has no issue, what you really want is that when you run

```
yield Request(url=urljoin(response.url, str(target)), \
                                  callback=self.parse_wikidata, \
                                  meta={"item": item})
```

It should `yield` sooner then the queued requests of below type

```
yield Request(url=urljoin(response.url, str(s)), \
                                  callback=self.parse, meta={"item": item})
```

If you look at the documentation

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

> **priority (int)** – the priority of this request (defaults to 0). The priority is used by the scheduler to define the order used to process requests. Requests with a higher priority value will execute earlier. Negative values are allowed in order to indicate relatively low-priority.

So you will use

```
yield Request(url=urljoin(response.url, str(target)), \
                                  callback=self.parse_wikidata, \
                                  meta={"item": item}, priority=1)
```

and

```
yield Request(url=urljoin(response.url, str(s)), \
                  callback=self.parse, meta={"item": item}, priority=-1)
```

This will make sure that the scraper gives priority to links which will results in data to scraped first